# Toggle images with push buttons in Processing

Tags: image, button, arduino, push, processing

I am trying to make a interactivity in wich when the person click the button, an image is shown, when clicked again it makes it disapear.
I have a prototype with 3 buttons, linked to 3 images differently.

```
import processing.serial.*;
import cc.arduino.*;
Arduino arduino;
boolean activo = false;
boolean vermelho = true;
PImage bg;
PImage img;
PImage img1;
PImage img2;

void setup() {
  size(700, 384);
  bg = loadImage("background.jpg");
  background(bg);
  arduino = new Arduino(this, "COM3", 57600);
  img = loadImage("background_1.png");
  img1 = loadImage("background_2.png");
  img2 = loadImage("background_3.png");

  arduino.pinMode(3, Arduino.INPUT);
  arduino.pinMode(5, Arduino.INPUT);
  arduino.pinMode(6, Arduino.INPUT);
}

void draw() {
    if (arduino.digitalRead(3) == Arduino.HIGH && activo) {
      if (vermelho) {
        image(img,0, 0);
        vermelho = false;
      } else {
        image(bg,0, 0);
        vermelho = true;
      }
      activo = false;
    }
    if (arduino.digitalRead(3) == Arduino.LOW && !activo) {
      activo = true;
     }


    if (arduino.digitalRead(5) == Arduino.HIGH && activo) {
        if (vermelho) {
          image(img1,0, 0);
          vermelho = false;
        } else {bf1e9ed8
          image(bg,0, 0);
          vermelho = true;
        }
    activo = false;
    }
    if (arduino.digitalRead(5) == Arduino.LOW && !activo) {
      activo = true;
    }



   if (arduino.digitalRead(6) == Arduino.HIGH && activo) {
        if (vermelho) {
          image(img2,0, 0);
          vermelho = false;
        } else {
          image(bg,0, 0);
          vermelho = true;
        }
    activo = false;
    }
    if (arduino.digitalRead(6) == Arduino.LOW && !activo) {
      activo = true;
    }
}
```

It works but the images are lagging . I don't know how to make this work everytime in right way